# Active device count seems low

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-console

The Google Play Console Dashboard gives a count of active devices. My app is a push-notification based app which provides communities with notifications of important events. So on my back-end I track each devices' Firebase push token, so that the users can receive notifications for the things they subscribe to. Whenever my back-end pushes a notification to a user that has uninstalled the app, disabled push notifications, or no longer has an active device, Firebase will indicate that error in the response. That entry is then removed from the back-end.

Considering that on average my system sends out at least one notification per day, I have an almost real-time count of how many users have my app installed on Android (whether or not they are using / launching it), and also have push notifications enabled for my app. Thus if anything this represents a sub-set of all installs, because some users may have disabled push notifications.

Some days I gain new app installs, but the overall total of app installs may go down, as there is always a baseline attrition due to people switching devices and not reinstalling the app, app uninstalls, etc. So I am certain my end is working correctly in removing entries for installs I can no longer push notifications to, as my counts on occasion go down (again, meaning that day there were more uninstalls than installs).

Now my question. My back-end count of active app installs (those I can actually send push notifications to) is significantly higher than what Google Console Dashboard reports for my active app installs. I show around 20% more installs than Google. Why the discrepancy? Surely Firebase isn't allowing thousands of phantom push destinations that it can no longer actually push to? Is this based on some kind of privacy setting for some people? I know in the Apple App Store they specifically state that the active install counts are opt-in only.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because Google Play Console only shows active installs for real users.

Firebase will be counting all the users which will include Google Bots used for Pre-Launch Reports as well as for reviewing the app to make sure it meets the policies.

Therefore, you will see a higher number in Firebase than Google Play Console.

Comment: To be more succinct - my higher count comes from active Firebase Cloud Messaging tokens. Those are installs of my app that I send push notifications to that respond. Further, we're talking a difference of around 1,000. Surely there are not that many Google Bots with my app installed.

Comment: For every update I release, I gain around 50 bots in firebase.

Comment: For one of my apps FCM shows 4 times more devices than Google Play.